# .Net Core 3 Razor pages catching 404

Tags: routes, razor-pages, .net-core-3.1

I am new in Razor pages, I built a prototype with 3 pages

host/Home
host/Login
host/Logout
host/Error

It is working but I am wondering how to catch a 404. E.g if I call host/nonEsistingPage or host/somethingelse I want to redirect to host/Home.

How can I achiev it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `UseStatusCodePages` middleware in .net core. By default, an ASP.NET Core app doesn't provide a status code page for HTTP status codes, such as 404 - Not Found.

call `UseStatusCodePages` in the `Startup.Configure method`:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

If you want to redirect to any specific url then use

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/host/Home?code={0}");
```

Explore more about app.UseStatusCodePages() on .Net Core documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1